# How do I download an jsp file into a pdf with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I need to download the jsp inside of an iframe using selenium. It has to be in a pdf format.

How do I manage to do this?

```
<iframe id="miBody" name="miBody" src="/padron-puc-constancia-internet/jsp/Constancia.jsp" height="150%" width="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" align="top" style="height: 629px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: What does that mean?  Do you want to download the code of the JSP?  Is the JSP supposed to give you a PDF?  Have you actually tried to load that page in Selenium?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897041/how-to-save-opened-page-as-pdf-in-selenium-python

Comment: @TimRoberts The page that loads is the same one I'm in but there's a document in there that can be saved as pdf through the computer ui so I cannot do it with selenium. So my only hope is somehow using the iframe of it to get it since the html points me in that direction.

Comment: Of course you can do it with selenium.  If you can download the document, then there must be a link that points to the PDF.  You just have to follow the link.