# Converting or printing all sections of rendered quarto document into html in one go

Tags: python, html, r, shiny, quarto

I want to convert [Shiny for Python](https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/docs/get-started.html) document into pdf. Jumping to each section and then printing into pdf is possible. However, wondering if there is a more compact way to print all sections in a one go.

Comment: Do you want to print one time? Do you want to do something like add a button and be able to print on demand? If one time, do you want to use the console in developer tools?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're going for. in any case, you could `document.querySelectorAll("a[href*=https]").forEach(x=> (console.log(x.href)))` to get all URLs (not recursively, obviously), then go to every url with selenium, wait  for the element to load (whatever way you want), and [screenshot](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/screenshot-element-method-selenium-python/) or [save as pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56897041/how-to-save-opened-page-as-pdf-in-selenium-python). perhaps remove unwanted elements before doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose a solution based on [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/index.html) and python (to scrape the links of html files for different sections of the docs and pass them to [`pdfkit`](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/), a python library which is a wrapper for `wkhtmltopdf` utility to convert HTML to PDF.

So at first download the [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and then install this tool on your system (you may read [this](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/convert-html-to-pdf-in-python#installing) to get help about installation process and **if you are a windows user remember to add `wkhtmltopdf` to PATH**).

Then check its availability from cmd/shell by,

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version

# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt)
```

Now then install these python libraries (assuming you have python installed),

```
pip install requests beautifulsoup4 pdfkit
```

and then run this python script,

```
$ python html2pdf.py
```

**html2pdf.py**

```py
import re
import pdfkit
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Making a GET request
r = requests.get('https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/docs/get-started.html')

# print(r.status_code)
  
# Parsing the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find_all('a', class_='sidebar-link')

# get the links
links = [link.get('href') for link in a if link.get('href') is not None]
site_link = 'https://shiny.rstudio.com/py'
full_links = [site_link + link[2:] for link in links]

# for file names
names = [re.findall("(?:.+\/)(.+)(?:.html)", link)[0] for link in full_links] 

# convert the link of htmls to pdf
for i, link in enumerate(full_links):
    pdfkit.from_url(link, f"{names[i]}.pdf")
```

It will convert all the html files (links in the sidebar of https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/docs/) into pdf files in one go.

```bash
$ ls

get-started.pdf            reactive-programming.pdf  ui-navigation.pdf
html2pdf.py                reactive-values.pdf       ui-page-layouts.pdf
overview.pdf               running-debugging.pdf     ui-static.pdf
putting-it-together.pdf    server.pdf                user-interface.pdf
reactive-calculations.pdf  ui-dynamic.pdf            workflow-modules.pdf
reactive-events.pdf        ui-feedback.pdf           workflow-server.pdf
reactive-mutable.pdf       ui-html.pdf
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks @shafee for very useful answer. The given script prints all sections, however, the print quality is not good.

Comment: Actually that would be the problem with automated printing. and i think even when you try to print those manually you dont have the full control over the quality. It depends on how the website author arranged things.

Comment: On a second thought, assuming the html files are rendered from qmd files (my guess), a script can be writtern to grab those qmd files and render them to pdf using quarto. But unfortunately I am having trouble to find the github repo for these qmd source file.